# How do I *ngIf and use interpolation?

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-template

I have a `userData$` observable which basically connects to firebase.  On this user object, is a bunch of optional properties.

I am using Ionic2 and I create the observable during `ionViewDidLoad` which is [described here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/)

This code

```
<h1 *ngIf="(userData$ | async)?.name">{{(userData$ | async)?.name}}</h1>
```

Causes me to have the following error

> FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error:
>   Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value:
>   'CD_INIT_VALUE'. Current value: ''. It seems like the view has been
>   created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has
>   it been created in a change detection hook ?

And in particular the first line on the stack trace is `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

What am I doing wrong here with that async template? If I delete `*ngIf` it works. If I change `...">Hello World"</h1>` it works.  But I can't do both here and not really sure why. I think that that ngif runs but the interpolation is missed.

Does anyone know why this happens or what the correct method should be?

Thanks!

Comment: At what point in your component life cycle do you initialize the observable `userData$` ?

Comment: I updated my answer. I am using `ionViewDidLoad` as I am using Ionic2, but I have tried doing crazy things, like in the constructor, or after a 10 second timeout.

Comment: angular2s dev mode executes each digest cycle 2x to compare results and if they differ you get this exception/error. Generally you should try to load data or make the data loading call in `ngOnInit` when you implement `OnInit`. If you do it in the constructor or at an arbitrary point in time you could see this err in dev. mode.